# Obtaining information from is dbp: ... of

Tags: sparql, dbpedia, sparqlwrapper

I am trying to get some information of the DBpedia page of Rodger Federer. I want to query in which years Roger Federer was flagbearer at the Olympic Games. I can extract information from normal property fields (`dbp:plays`), but not if the property is of the format (`is dbp:flagbearer of`).

Can someone give me some advise how to extract the years in which Roger Federer was flagbearer and possibly give a query?

Comment: do you know the required predicate for that flag bearer or the class of the winner ? I came up with this query `select * where 
{
 values ?you {<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Roger_Federer>}
 ?you <http://purl.org/dc/terms/subject> ?o
}` check if it has some interesting values for you

Comment: Unfortunately it does not yield any interesting values. Any other advise?

Comment: no I'm sorry .... I'm not so familiar with the tense vocabularies

Answer (score 2):

You can get that information using the following query.

```
PREFIX dbp:<http://dbpedia.org/property/>

select ?olympics ?year where { 
   ?olympics dbp:flagbearer <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Roger_Federer>;
             dbp:games ?year .
}
```

This query will give you the following results in [DBpedia](http://dbpedia.org/sparql).

```
+---------------------------------------------+------+
|                  olympics                   | year |
+---------------------------------------------+------+
| dbr:Switzerland_at_the_2008_Summer_Olympics | 2008 |
| dbr:Switzerland_at_the_2004_Summer_Olympics | 2004 |
+---------------------------------------------+------+
```